# Apache NiFi || How to pass powershell command in Executeprocess processor

Tags: apache-nifi

Apache NiFi || How to pass powershell command in Executeprocess processor.

I want to execute powershell script on remote computer so can someone tell me how to pass the parameter in executeprocess processor.

Comment: Read processor documentation http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/ some parameters supports nifi expression language: http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html